# Easiest way to share development secrets in aspnetcore application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I want to store a development-time secret somewhere outside of my code repository, that developers are able to use without any manual tasks. (As close to `Build, Run, and it will just work`).

The secrets have to be configured in the aspnetcore Configuration Builder like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json";
builder.AddDevelopmentSecrets(...);
```

The official recommendation by the aspnetcore team seems to be to use the [Secret Manager Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?tabs=visual-studio). But this requires every developer to configure the secrets manually. For example, they'd have to run `dotnet user-secrets set key value` for every secret.

The 2nd thing I looked at was Azure KeyVault. This seemed ideal, because I'd only have to call `builder.AddAzureKeyVault(...)`. The only problem is that I'd have to store the clientId and clientSecret to access the keyvault somewhere.

Ideally I want something that the `AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio` extension does. Once the extension is installed, you simply login with your AWS credentials and the extension simply injects your credentials into every official AWS call that is used.

Does Azure have anything like this? Something that allows me to inject (or access) my Azure credentials, so they can be used in the call to `AddAzureKeyVault(...)`? And if not, what's the closest solution that comes close to this?

Comment: Managed Service Identity comes pretty close: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-managed-service-identity But I haven't tried to use it with the config system.

Comment: @juunas Looks perfect! I'll try it out immediately. :)

Comment: @juunas Absolutely perfect. I'm so happy now. See the updated question for the code to make it work. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure AD Managed Service Identity can help here. The implementation based on my suggestion:

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback)); 
builder.AddAzureKeyVault("https://x.vault.azure.net/", keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

Now you can sign in to the Azure CLI 2.0 and those credentials will be automatically used to access KeyVault.

You can read more about MSI here: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-managed-service-identity

Answer (score 3):

To extend on @juunas his answer: Visual Studio 15.5 was just released which makes this even easier. If you've logged onto your Azure account from Visual Studio (and you have installed the currently in preview [Azure Services Authentication Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrismann.MicrosoftVisualStudioAsalExtension)), Visual Studio will simply take care of the Azure KeyVault authentication.

You only need to specify the KeyVault url in `launchSettings.json` under the environement variables. No need for Azure CLI, or the [AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/) library.

This even works on the full .NET Framework, not just ASP.NET Core.

See:

- General: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/11/17/managing-secrets-securely-in-the-cloud/
- ASP.NET Core Example: https://github.com/CawaMS/aspnetcore-msi-keyvault